# getting error DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

i have create `test.js` file, and installed one npm library, when i run the file i am getting below error, i tried to use `npm i puppeteer` this library but i am getting error when i tried to install it, so i used this library `npm i puppeteer-core`

```
(node:30075) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:30075) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

here is my full code for test.js file

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?

Comment: Try adding `.catch(err=>{console.log(err)});` and see what logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `async/await`, it is recommended to use `try/catch` catch the error, and to figure out what's wrong.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    // Do whatever you want, throw the error again if you want but it will just produce `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` again, if you throw it again.
  }
})();
```